# Is the Pelias-android-sdk library still functional?

Tags: android, pelias

I want to implement a location autocomplete feature in android. I am using osmdroid to display the map. When i include the below dependancy:

```
implementation 'com.mapzen.android:pelias-android-sdk:1.3.1'
```

I get the following error: 
    Failed to resolve: com.mapzen.android:pelias-android-sdk:1.3.1

So i just want to know if the library is working if not which other library can i use(Other than google maps API) to achieve the same function

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week. Please use the latest tag version.

```
implementation 'com.mapzen.android:pelias-android-sdk:1.2.1'
```

Hope that helps :)